# how to create a dynamic interface for my props when my action call and data coming from api in redux using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

i'm trying to create my interface to my props for the api given below:
link: https://medi-pharma.herokuapp.com/api/report

my interface:

```
export interface SettingCategoryAddItemProps {
  items: any;
}
```

and accessing in my component like this

```
console.log(this.props.items)}
```

but this gives me a complex object. if i would try to access its child i whould go back to my interface and change it. then i can access.

**is there any way to make my interface dynamic according to the data coming from my actions?**

Answer (score 0):

Types don't exist at runtime they go through a process of "Type Erasure" https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure but also even if it was possible it would be useless because types also have no effect on the actual run time code they only exist to check things at compile time.

There are tools that given the structure of JSON will generate you interfaces (code generators), however i find their output generally poor quality and normally its better to just do them by hand.